How to present the relation between two KPIs
The case is for a logistics company. We are trying to show our users their current emissions and how much emissions they can save/avoid/reduce by choosing more sustainable routing options. On our dashboard we would like to show users a KPI for this, so they can more easily keep track and communicate with their stakeholders. For instance "Boss, we can reduce 40% of our emissions if we choose more sustainable routes on 25% of our routes. 75% of our routes are already fine"
NB: we have other graphs to identify the actual hotspots. As it could be that only 2 routes are responsible for that 40% of avoidable emissions.
The challenge

Make the relation understood between projected emissions and avoidable emissions on the one hand and the percentage of routes that have more sustainable alternatives on the other.
Should fit on a relatively small component.

What I tried so far


I would recommend a Pareto chart.
Order your routes in decreasing order of emissions savings possible if they were changed. Then plot these savings in a barchart. In addition, include a line of cumulative savings, possibly with a second vertical axis at the right. If the part about what percentage of routes to change is important, then add this cumulative percentage as a horizontal axis at the bottom. You could also emphasize your key message "reduce 40% of emissions by changing 25% of routes" by putting in a vertical line at 25% of route changes, which should intersect the cumulative emissions savings line at 40%, so put another horizontal line there.
If you have few routes, you might be able to make the bars clickable for a deep dive, or to have your tool display mouseover information when your pointer hovers over it. Alternatively, show the full plot above, and a version with only the top 5-10 routes with the largest savings potential, so you can have this functionality here and not in the full chart with too many bars.

R code:
savings_percent <- c(10,8,7,6,5,2,2,rep(1,7),rep(0,14))
plot(savings_percent,type="h",lwd=5,xlab="",ylab="savings",
    ylim=c(0,max(cumsum(savings_percent))),las=1)
lines(cumsum(savings_percent),type="b")
legend("right",lwd=c(5,1),pch=c(NA,1),legend=c("Savings per route","Cumulative savings"))
abline(h=40,v=7.5,lty=2)


This is really interesting! Thanks a bunch! Ill note it as solved. It might be too complex for an initial representation for our audience, but as a deep dive it works really well
